# Jquery serialize() triggering 403 when open PHP tag entered in textarea

Tags: serialization, mod-security

So I've been going through my forms recently to check my SQL queries are secure along with sanitizing any input and have just found that entering `<?` into a text box triggers a 403 before it even hits the processing file, I can only assume it must be related to mod_security??

My question is, is this something to just not worry about if it's controlled by the web host as I'm using shared hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently ran into a problem with submitting form data via a GET request to the server after using jQuery's .serialize() function for the submitted variables. These were web apps that had worked flawlessly for years. It turned out that after a recent ModSecurity rule set update, I was triggering the 211700 (HTTP redirect) and 217280 (smuggling attack) rules in Comodo's WAF ruleset, which the server uses with ModSecurity. I wasn't getting a 403. My IP address got blocked by the firewall. :(

The fix was switching my AJAX code to use to POST instead of GET, and not using .serialize(). I still have some web apps that use .serialize() and GET requests via AJAX without triggering ModSecurity, so I believe it is also necessary to pass suspect characters, as you discovered, though in my testing, all I was using was parentheses.

Since you're on a shared server, it's probably not possible--or worth your time--to find out what rule set the host is using, so your best bet is most likely to switch your form submissions to using POST instead of GET, and not use .serialize(). I figure those rules are there for a reason, and a better approach is to avoid having my code look like it's doing something nefarious than to disable the rules.